# I am new to using Excel VBA for data forms

Tags: excel

I have some problematic code,

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If VBA.IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) = False Then
MsgBox "Only numeric values are accepted in the Time Spent", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If
If OptionButton1.Value Then
sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Direct")
lastrow = sht.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value Then
sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("indirect")
lastrow = sht.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If

With Range("a" & lastrow).Value = TextBox1.Value
Range("b" & lastrow).Value = TextBox2.Value
Range("c" & lastrow).Value = ComboBox1.Value
End With
sht.Activate

End Sub
```

I also am having issues with my combo box to have set values in it, and the code is as follows

```
Private Sub TimeEntry_Initialize()
  ComboBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tasks").Range("A1:A5").Value
End Sub
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You do not mention what problem you are facing. Your `TimeEntry_Initialize()` codes seems okay. Problem is `With` block codes. You do not refer proper sheet name to range object. `With Range("a" & lastrow).Value` to this code code you have to refer sheet name.

Comment: Ultimately I am trying to have a form populate data into different sheets in the same workbook depending on which option button is chosen. The form has 2 textbox fields, 1 combo box, and 2 option buttons. I try to run the debug and I keep getting this section of code highlighted yellow```If OptionButton1.Value Then
sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Direct")
lastrow = sht.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value Then
sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("indirect")
lastrow = sht.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.